# How do I access tuple struct fields in a gdb pretty printer?

Tags: rust, gdb

Attempting to write a gdb pretty printer for a tuple struct of mine following [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/attributes/debugger.html#using-debugger_visualizer-with-gdb), I stumbled upon the fact that the obvious `val['0']` to access the field `0` of the tuple struct fails with an error at run-time:

```
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member named 0.
```

How can I access a tuple struct field, then?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: prefix the field number by double-underscore, ie use `val['__0']` for the 0-th field.**

It is possible to introspect the values passed by gdb by writing an introspection printer:

```py
class IntrospectionPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.__val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return '[' + ', '.join((f'{f.name}' for f in self.__val.type.fields())) + ']'
```

This will return a list of the fields available, printing `None` when a field is anonymous. For a tuple struct with a single field, this gives:

```
$1 = [__0]
```

From which we learn that the field is called `__0`, not just `0`.